# Prove that $10101\ldots01$ can't be a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $10101\ldots01$, where the sequence $"01"$ is repeated $k$ times can't be a perfect square for any value of $k$.

All I managed to prove is that the general formula is $1+\frac {100}{99}(100^k-1)$ but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: It is enough to write $\dfrac{100^k-1}{99}$, where $k>1$.

Comment: Perhaps that you ment to ask that it can't be a perfect square for *any* value of $k$. Of course that it can't be a perfect square for *all* values of $k$ since it isn't a perfect square when $k=1$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, edited the question (apologies - I am Italian!)

Comment: After multiplying it by $33^2$, we'll get expression $$11\times(100^k-1).$$ Maybe roll around it?

Comment: Hint: Consider this modulo $8$

Comment: I also found the recursive relation: f(0)=1 and f(n)=100*f(n-1)+1

Answer (score 5):

An odd square has to be $\equiv 1 \bmod 8$ because$(2m+1)^2=4m^2+4m+1=4m(m+1)+1$ where $m(m+1)$ is even.  Any number rendered in base $10$ is a multiple of $1000=125×8$ plus its last three digits, thus congruent with the last three digits $\bmod 8$.  But $101 \equiv 5 \bmod 8$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the statement is true.

Note that any odd square integer can be written as $8m+1$, where $m$ is a positive integer.(*)

Let, $\dfrac{100^k-1}{99}=8m+1$, where $m$ is a positive integer.

Now, $\dfrac{100^k-1}{99}=8m+1\Rightarrow 100^k=99(8m+1)+1=(99\times8)m+100
\\\Rightarrow (99\times8)m=100(100^{k-1}-1)\Rightarrow m=\dfrac{25}{2}\times\dfrac{100^{k-1}-1}{99}$

Note that, for $k>1$, $\dfrac{100^{k-1}-1}{99}$ is an odd integer.

since $k>1$, $m$ can not be an integer. $\Rightarrow \Leftarrow$

---

(*) Why an odd square integer can be written of the form $8m+1$?

$\Longrightarrow$ Note that $(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1=4n(n+1)+1=8m+1$, since $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is an positive integer.(note that $n$ and $n+1$ are consecutive integers)

Comment: Perhaps you should add a footnote to justify why $(100^{k-1}-1)/99$ is an odd integer too...

Comment: @skyking why you say so, isn't trivial $2\nmid (100^{k-1}-1)$

Comment: Well justification of that is the same as the justification that the numbers are $(100^k-1)/99$...

Comment: @MANMAID: I understand that you assume that $\dfrac{100^k-1}{99}=$Odd square integer, but why odd?

Comment: @MANMAID Yes, but it should be divisible by $99$ as well to make it an integer.

Comment: I don't say it's complicated, but then the fact that odd squares can be written on the form $8m+1$ isn't complicated either.

Comment: are you sure @skyking see that OP commented why $\dfrac{100^k-1}{99}$ is odd!

Comment: @MANMAID yes indeed it is odd, but how can we prove it?

Comment: @HarryPetrone your number $1010\dots 01=\dfrac{100^k-1}{99}$, for some $k$, note that that number ends with $1$, how that could be even *even* number!

Comment: @HarryPetrone note $2$ does not divides $100^k-1$, since $2$ divides $100^k$

Comment: @MANMAID yes thank you - I am still asleep :)

Comment: Simpler:  Any positive whole number rendered in base$10$ is congruent to its last three digits $\bmod 8$. $101\equiv 5$.

Comment: indeed @OscarLanzi why don't you write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help you :$$101010101...01=\\\overline{0101010101...01}=\\\overline{01}+100\times\overline{01}+100^2\times \overline{01}+100^3\times \overline{01}+...+100^m\times \overline{01}=\\\overline{01}(1+100+100^2+100^3+...+100^m)=\\
\overline{01}(\frac{100^{m+1}-1}{99})=\\(\frac{100^{m+1}-1}{99})=k^2 \\100^{m+1}-1=99k^2\\100^{m+1}=99k^2+1=\\100k^2+1-k^2=\\(10k)^2+(1-k^2) \to\\1-k^2=0 \to k=1 \text{ for k=1 this not true }$$

Comment: This doesn't in anyway prove that it is true for other values of k.

Comment: @WinVineeth :you are right , I don't claim that's a proof . I said may be help

Answer (score -1):

It can be proved by the conclusions of the following 2 points:$$$$
1.  Suppose we take k = 1,
In this case, 101 is 1 more than 100 (the nearest perfect square). $$$$
similarly, for any value of k, the nearest perfect square will be  1 less than the number. ex. for k=2, 10101 nearest square ->  10000(  $100^2$ ),for k=3, 1010101 -> 1,000,000(  $ 1000^2$ ) $$$$
2. Now Observe the following pattern $$$$
$2^2$ - $1^2$ = 4-1 = 3 $$$$
$3^2$ - $2^2$ = 9-4 =5 $$$$ . $$$$ . $$$$
$(x+1)^2$ - $x^2$ = $x^2$ + 2x +1 - $x^2$ = 2x+1 $$$$
Clearly the difference between square of two consecutive **CAN NOT BE 1** for any value of k.
Ex. for k =1 the nearest squares are 100 and 121 and difference is 21.
    for k=2 these are 10000 and 10201 and difference is 201 and so on .

So any for any value of k 10101010....01 can not be perfect square.

Comment: Your first point is false because for $k=3$ we have $1001^2=1002001 < 1010101$ so the directly preceding perfect square is *not* $1000000$.

Comment: @skyking In fact, $1004^2 = 1008032064$ is even closer, while $1005^2 = 1010050125$ is the closest, although it's larger.

Comment: In addition another part of the claim is false $10101-10000 = 101$ which is **not** $1$. The fact that the difference is $1$ is used in the next part of the "proof". This invalidates the "proof" for any $k>1$.